# Gradle installs incorrect side by side NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a strange problem with side by side NDK. I have defined `ndkVersion` as `21.2.6472646` in my project and I have already installed this side by side version. But when I sync my project, gradle looks for version `21.1.6352462` and downloads and installs this strange version.

Any idea why this happens?

Best Regards

**Update:**

I'm using android studio 4.1.1 and here what I have used in gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ndkVersion '21.2.6472646'
    ...
}
```

But after sync, project is synced for ndk version `21.1.6352462` which can also be verified at build log files.

**Update 2:**

Here is project settings view:
[image]

Comment: What's version Android Studio you use? If <= 3.5, NDK side by side  is irrelevant. If not please show your config ndk in build.gralde and config path to ndk

Comment: @Tungken everything seems correct, but I updated question.

Comment: Can you check NDK available version in File>Project Structure>SDK Location>Android NDK Location, press dropdown button for see them. If your version not appear, NDK has problem. @Afshin

Comment: If ^ doesn't fix it file a bug.

Comment: @Tungken Android NDK location is disabled and does not show anything. Should it be enabled in case that we use side by side NDK too? I should say that if I manually specify ndk.location in my local.properties file, everything works fine.

Comment: @DanAlbert added a picture from module view. NDK location is disabled but ndk version is specified for module.

Comment: Like I said, file a bug.